# REGEX for 2 date formats

Tags: regex

I want to allow 2 different date formats:

> 1/1/2017 and 1-JAN-2017

I am using this regex but its not working:

```
re = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})|[0-9]{1,2}\-[a-zA-Z]{3}\-[0-9]{4}/;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group the alternatives and add the end of string anchor:

```
re = /^(?:\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4})$/;
       ^^^                       ^                         ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4aYoE/1).

Without the grouping construct, the `^` is only applied to `(\d{1,2})`, and the other alternative is searched for at any position in the string.

Without the `$` anchor, the pattern can match even if the pattern found is not at the end of the string (and you will get partial matches).